# Nothing known about base class if custom template class used

Tags: c++, go, swig

I'm trying to wrap libsnark, a c++ project, to golang.
I got the following warnings,

```
SWIG:1: Warning 125: Use of the include path to find the input file is deprecated and will not work with ccache. Please include the path when specifying the input file.
./go_wrapper/swig/../../libsnark/libsnark/gadgetlib2/variable.hpp:320: Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'VariableArrayContents'. Ignored.
./go_wrapper/swig/../../libsnark/libsnark/gadgetlib2/variable.hpp:332: Warning 315: Nothing known about 'VariableArrayContents::operator []'.
./go_wrapper/swig/../../libsnark/libsnark/gadgetlib2/variable.hpp:333: Warning 315: Nothing known about 'VariableArrayContents::at'.
```

here is the c++ snippet

```cpp
class Variable {
   /**
    * @brief allocates the variable
    */
public:
    explicit Variable(const ::std::string& name = "");
    virtual ~Variable();
    ...
}; // class Variable

typedef ::std::vector<Variable> VariableArrayContents;

class VariableArray : public VariableArrayContents {
   public:
    using VariableArrayContents::operator[];
    using VariableArrayContents::at;
    using VariableArrayContents::push_back;
    using VariableArrayContents::size;

   ... 
}
```

and this is my swig file

```
%module gadgetlib2

%include <typemaps.i>
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_string.i"


%ignore VariableArrayContents;
typedef std::vector<Variable> VariableArrayContents;
%{
typedef std::vector<Variable> VariableArrayContents;
%}
namespace std {
   %template(StringVector) vector<string>;
   %template(VariableArrayContentsVector) vector<Variable>;
   // Use this, got the same result 
   // %template(VariableArrayContentsVector) vector<Variable>;
}


%include "../../libsnark/libsnark/gadgetlib2/variable.hpp"
%include "../../libsnark/libsnark/gadgetlib2/variable_operators.hpp"
%include "../../libsnark/libsnark/gadgetlib2/protoboard.hpp"
%include "../../libsnark/libsnark/gadgetlib2/pp.hpp"
...
```

I'm new to SWIG, not very know how to write such complex script. The c++ project is a 3rd party project, we don't plan to touch it.